# Вопрос по 9-patch png

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне нужно для блока динамической высоты и ширины сделать тень, для этого как я понял используется 9-path изображения, с мета указаниями что где нужно растягивать.

Я получил вот такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тень появилась, но фон блока стал серым, а не белым как нужно.

Что я сделал не так, и еще вопрос, нужно ли такие изображения делать под разные dpi?

UPD

Результат:

[image]

Фон белый только по центру, а по нижней и верхней границы сероватые...

Comment: Приложите картинку с результатом "фон блока стал серым, а не белым"

Comment: под разные dpi делать 9-patch обычно не требуется, однако строгих ограничений на этот счет не существует. Если вы видите, что на какой-то плотности результат выглядит не так, как ожидается (пикселизация и тп.) никто не запрещает вам использовать для этой плотности отдельный 9-patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Дело было в том, что такое изображение (9-patch) нужно было поместить в папку drawable-nodpi что бы мой градиент не растягивался еще и по плотности экрана, так вместо рамки в 5 px получаешь ее 10px в xhdpi, это первый момент.
Второй момент, заключается в том что нужно оставлять отступы фона (в моем случае белого) по бокам рамки, иначе может получиться что рамка немного распространилась на фон с краев, не знаю почему это происходит, возможно из-за не точности растягивания...
Вот что получилось в итоге:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь любым инструментом, типа этого
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
чтобы проверить как он растягивается.

Но судя по картинке с результатом, у Вас еще что-то в фоне есть.